# table headers not aligning properly

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I am outputing 4 columns from a mysql query, but using the code below doesnt align each column wiht the headers, I guess is due the fact this are static declared against the dynamic rows . Can someone advise a way to align the headers properly with each fetched column ,,,

```
$tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px"; 
    $tdStyle = "padding:5px "; 
    $thStyle = "padding:5px; align:center ";


    echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">'; 
    echo "<tr> <th>Quiz Title </th><th> Score </th><th>Maximum Score </th><th>Finished On </th></tr>"; 

    $row = $database->loadRowList();
    foreach($row as $valuearray)
    {
    echo '<tr style=" align="center">';
    foreach($valuearray as $field)
    {

    echo "<td>$field</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: When you say the are not aligned, what do you mean? Do you mean you end up with extra cells in the data rows, or do you mean the columns aren't in the right order?

Comment: First off, there is a mistake in your attempt to center the `<tr>` there's a `"` which is never closed. Also pick either `align="center"` or `style="text-align: center"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Joomla? The `loadRowList()` suggests this. If you are, then use `loadAssocList()` instead, which returns the field names as well as the field values. You can do then a separate loop to output your column headers and guarantee they match up with the data fields.

---

docs for the function here: http://help.joomla.org/content/view/509/60/

you'd do something like:

```
$rows = $database->loadAssocList();
echo '<tr>';
foreach(array_keys($rows[0]) as $header) {
    echo "<th>$header</th>";
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Yes Marc B I am using Joomla , can you please help on how the syntax would be to output the table?

Comment: That worked well ! however I am not sure how to set an alias to each column on the query.

Comment: Don't know Joomla well enough, but if you're writing the query yourself, then do `select field1 AS alias1, field2 AS alias2 etc...`.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
echo '<tr style=" align="center">';
```

I think you want:

```
echo '<tr style="text-align:center;">';
```

Comment: as an FYI, I don't think the style belongs on that element, but at least it'll be well formed.

Comment: Not `align: center`, but `text-align: center`. +1 when you change that.

Comment: Hah changed it just for you; I was more concerned about the malformed HTML.